# removing "enter parameter value" in query MS access

Tags: ms-access

So I'm as much of a beginner as can be. I barely know how to code and I'm learning Access as I go.

I have two tables: EmployeesT (has employees basic info) and IncreaseT (has a record for each time each employee has been given an increase in their salary)

I'm currently stuck with a query that should do the following:

1. Show me only the last record each employee had an increase > 0
2. Count the number of months it has been since the last time that
   employee had their last increase
3. Show either "ok", "eligible", or "overdue" based on the Rating (a
   field in IncreaseT) of the employee and the number of months since
   his last increase

My problem is that when I try to open the query, it asks me to "enter parameter value" for:

> Last of Rating (Rating field with Last total),
>
> Max of DateOfLastUpdate (DateOfLastUpdate field with Max total), and
>
> MonthsSinceLastUpdate (DateDiff("m",[MaxOfDateOfUpdate],Now())

This is the code for the query:

```
SELECT EmployeesT.LocalID, Last(IncreaseT.Ratings) AS LastOfRatings, Max(IncreaseT.DateOfUpdate) AS MaxOfDateOfUpdate, DateDiff("m",[MaxOfDateOfUpdate],Now()) AS MonthsSinceLastIncrease, IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<24,IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=18 And [LastOfRatings]<=2,"Overdue",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=15 And [LastOfRatings]=1,"Overdue",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=9 And [MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<15 And [LastOfRatings]=1,"Eligible",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=12 And [MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<18 And [LastOfRatings]=2,"Eligible","ok")))),"Overdue") AS Eligiblity

FROM EmployeesT INNER JOIN IncreaseT ON EmployeesT.LocalID = IncreaseT.Employee
WHERE (((IncreaseT.Increase)>0))
GROUP BY EmployeesT.LocalID, DateDiff("m",[MaxOfDateOfUpdate],Now()), IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<24,IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=18 And [LastOfRatings]<=2,"Overdue",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=15 And [LastOfRatings]=1,"Overdue",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=9 And [MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<15 And [LastOfRatings]=1,"Eligible",IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease]>=12 And [MonthsSinceLastIncrease]<18 And [LastOfRatings]=2,"Eligible","ok")))),"Overdue");
```

any help would be very appreciated, I tried to read other posts and apply the same logic into mine but no luck, I did my whole thing in design view and everything in code is just too confusing for me

Comment: You cannot use the aliases you created in the select list in the group by list. You need to repeat the entire expressions there because group by clause is executed before the select list.

Comment: THANK YOU! I kept reading about aliases a bunch of places but couldn't figure out exactly what they are! Now I kind of do. So what I did is break this one query into a bunch of other ones, so I can make sure they're executed in the order I need them to be. It works! Another confusing problem came up -the IIF condition now gets me two records for some of the employees instead of one- but I'll keep at it till I get what I want, thanks again!