# MS access if condition doesn't work

Tags: if-statement, ms-access-2010

I used to have one query that does a bunch of things, one of them is tell me about the salary increase for each employee. Is it due? is it overdue? is it too early for one?

The query kept asking me to enter parameters and after asking this question [removing "enter parameter value" in query MS access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191253/removing-enter-parameter-value-in-query-ms-access) I broke the one query into a bunch, each query builds on the other until the last one that has the if condition.
Everything worked exactly the way I want it to, except for the if condition (that used to work fine before!!!)

This is my if condition

```
    Eligibility: IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 24, IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 18
        AND [LastOfRatings] <= 2, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 15
            AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 9
                AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 15
                AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "Eligible", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 12
                    AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 18
                    AND [LastOfRatings] = 2, "Eligible", "ok")))), "OVERDUE")
```

The rule for salary increases are as follows:

- If the employee's rating is 3, he gets an increase after 24 months of
  his last one
- If the employee's rating is 2, he gets one in 12-18
  months
- If the employee's rating is 1, he gets one in 9-15 months

What happens now, is that for some of the employees, I get only one record and it's correct, but for some employees, I get two records, one of them is correct an the other is not. Now instead of 48 records (what I used to get when the condition worked fine), I get 58.

This is the code for the whole query

```
SELECT IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 24, IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 18
            AND [LastOfRatings] <= 2, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 15
                AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 9
                    AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 15
                    AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "Eligible", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 12
                        AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 18
                        AND [LastOfRatings] = 2, "Eligible", "ok")))), "OVERDUE") AS Eligibility
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.LocalID
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.LastOfRatings
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.MaxOfDateOfUpdate
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.MonthsSinceLastIncrease
FROM MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ
    ,DateOfUpdateQ
GROUP BY IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 24, IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 18
            AND [LastOfRatings] <= 2, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 15
                AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "OVERDUE", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 9
                    AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 15
                    AND [LastOfRatings] = 1, "Eligible", IIf([MonthsSinceLastIncrease] >= 12
                        AND [MonthsSinceLastIncrease] < 18
                        AND [LastOfRatings] = 2, "Eligible", "ok")))), "OVERDUE")
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.LocalID
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.LastOfRatings
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.MaxOfDateOfUpdate
    ,MonthsSinceLastUpdateQ.MonthsSinceLastIncrease;
```

Your help is much appreciated, please note that I barely know coding and have only been learning MS Access as I go, thank you!

Comment: How many rows returns DateOfUpdateQ? Both queries are not linked, this may cause records duplicating. DateOfUpdateQ

Comment: DateOfUpdateQ returns 48. How do I link the queries?

Comment: Use `JOIN` or just drag-and-drop columns which should be joined in query builder.

Comment: When I drag and drop I get 2340 records :/ trying to figure out how to write a join in SQL now. Shouldn't it be a union rather than a join? I don't know neither yet, but I'm looking into it and from what I understand it seems like I need a union

Comment: NVM it worked by dragging and dropping!! I thought I was supposed to drag columns, turns out I have to do it like a relationship! Thank you so much!!

Comment: How can I mark the question as solved? Thanks again I'm so happy it finally worked!!!

Comment: I added answer, if it solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables in your query not linked. Link related colums in query designer by drag-and-drop, like relationship creation